# how are stored procedure inserted/uploaded into database

Tags: postgresql, node.js

I'm just a noob developer and I have a stored procedure I've created for postgres. The app I'm developing has backend done in `node` and I've got to upload the stored procedure to our dev server.

How is this process usually done? I mean, I could just copy the code and paste it on our dev's `pgadmin` and that would work. But, creating a `migration` file for that would also work. Also, executing a `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` raw query inside the code itself would also work.

How is the process of uploading a stored procedure on a postgres running server usually done?

Comment: Keep your stored procedure creation scripts in git or svn (or whichever source control system you use). Then all you have to do is run that script to create it.

Comment: yeah, but, @Colin'tHart , how would we run a script for postgres outside of it? Are you suggesting some sort of a raw ORM query?

Comment: It’s as easy as `psql -f script.sql`

Answer (score 1):

You just connect to the postgres database instance, run the `create procedure` query, grant permissions to execute it to whatever role/users that you want to grant access to, and call it a day.